# Compatibility problem between WPML and Divi on Dynamic content

Tags: wordpress, wpml, divi-theme

I need to translate a Divi theme with WPML on Wordpress and I have a compatibility problem.
I have a Title h1 that is called in "use content dynamic" of Divi but when I translate my page, it gives me an incomprehensible formatted string: @ET-DC@eyJkeW5hbWljIjp0cnVlLCJjb250ZW50IjoiY3VzdG9tX21ldGFfdGl0bGVfaDEiLCJzZXR0aW5ncyI6eyJiZWZvcmUiOiIiLCJhZnRlciI6IiIsImVuYWJsZV9odG1sIjoib2ZmIn19@

[wpml translation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ceqp.png)

[Untranslated block rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6GSK.png)

[Translated block rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9Fmv.png)

At the moment, I'm modifying this by hand, but at the slightest translation it jumps, is there a way around this?

Comment: Place your question in WPML support forum or ask Divi support. In string translations plugin set how should be translated. If that doesnt help you can go with wpml config option or po/mo file option depends on your situation.